# How to get the value using jq command?

Tags: jq

How to get the value of filecode in

```
"{"msg": "OK", "status": 200, "files": [ { "filecode":"am9kb3tw6hv1", "filename": "video.mp4", "status": "OK" } ]}"
```

The printed output will be

```
am9kb3tw6hv1
```

Answer (score 2):

I supposed your file name is test.json

```
echo {\"msg\": \"OK\", \"status\": 200, \"files\": [ { \"filecode\":\"am9kb3tw6hv1\", \"filename\": \"video.mp4\", \"status\": \"OK\" } ]} > test.json
```

Run this

```
jq '.files[0].filecode' test.json
```

Output

```
"am9kb3tw6hv1"
```

If you don't want the quotes, then use -r

```
jq -r '.files[0].filecode' test.json
```

output

```
am9kb3tw6hv1
```

I found [this](https://tecadmin.net/linux-jq-command) page that explain how to use jq

Comment: jq '.files[0].filecode' output.json is parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 5

Comment: This is probably because you are not escaping the quotes. Try this command and retry `echo {\"msg\": \"OK\", \"status\": 200, \"files\": [ { \"filecode\":\"am9kb3tw6hv1\", \"filename\": \"video.mp4\", \"status\": \"OK\" } ]} > test.json`